# Toast is showing every time I request location, how to change

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps-markers

Hey my code is requesting location every momement and on the onLocationChanged method I have a toast which shows the GPS address, the problem is that onLocationChanged is getting called every moment while I don't want a Toast of the location every moment because I end up being spammed with Toasts, is there a way to change this to something that could be more nice for the user?

```
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                mMap.clear();
                LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Your Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 15));

                Context context;
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                try {
                    List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                    if (listAddresses != null && listAddresses.size() > 0)
                    {
                        if (listAddresses.get(0).getThoroughfare() != null)
                        {
                            address += listAddresses.get(0).getThoroughfare() + " ";
                        }
                        if (listAddresses.get(0).getLocality() != null)
                        {
                            address += listAddresses.get(0).getLocality() + " ";
                        }
                        if (listAddresses.get(0).getPostalCode() != null)
                        {
                            address += listAddresses.get(0).getPostalCode() + " ";
                        }
                        if (listAddresses.get(0).getAdminArea() != null)
                        {
                            address += listAddresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(MapAcvitiy.this, address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i("Address", address);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Another part of my code is this where I create a locationManager and set the requestLocationUpdates to request the location ever moment.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        } else {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
            }else {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                mMap.clear();
                LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Your Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 15));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a global variable `long toastTime=0` and in your onLocationChanged put `toastTime+=10` and replace if statement in your code

```html
if(toastTime%1000==0)/*you can change 1000 to another value if you want*/{
toastTime=0;  
Toast.makeText(MapAcvitiy.this,address,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
}
```

not perfect but it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

could add the global variable isToastShow to make the toast only once.

```
    boolean isToastShow =false;

    if(!isToastShow){
        Toast.makeText(MapAcvitiy.this, address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        isToastShow = true;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove the toast or you have to use `onLocationUpdateRemove()` and you can display address in TextView it will updating when `onLocationUpdate()` called

Comment: You've misspelled your method names